# UIButton not clickable when custom view called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, user-interaction

I am new to iPhone development,I need help in understanding the below,as I am able to create newView using the following

```
UIView *newView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30)]; 
newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *newViewBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


newViewBtn.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x+5,
                            newView.frame.origin.y+5,60,20);
[newView addSubview:newViewBtn];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Above code is working without any problem. But when I try to create the view using the following, view is created alright, but the button on the view is not clickable.

```
int randNumX = arc4random() % 150;
int randNumY = arc4random() % 200;
UIView newView=[[UIView alloc]init];
newView.frame =CGRectMake(randNumX, randNumY, 80, 30);

newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UIButton *newViewBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
newViewBtn.frame  = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x+5
                         ,newView.frame.origin.y+5,60,20);
[newView addSubview:newViewBtn];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

and there is one another scenario if change the following code

```
 newViewBtn.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x+5
                          ,newView.frame.origin.y+5,60,20);
```

with the code below app crashes

```
 newViewBtn.frame =CGRectMake(randNumX+5,randNumY+5,60,20);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,thanks in advance.

I have added the following code already

```
     newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclick:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     -(void)btnclick:(id)sender
     {
       //my code
     }
```

It is working in the first case:

My main concern here is when the newView is draw ,why the button on this view is not clickable

Comment: Have you added the button to the view? `[newView addSubview:newViewBtn];`

Comment: @GameDevGuru :Yes, i added the button

Comment: @Aiden Have you tried my code.. i'm damn sure it will help you.

Comment: My main concern here is when the newView is draw ,why the button on  this view is not clickable

Comment: @Aiden Try my answer and see if you receive response when button clicked.

Comment: @GameDevGuru :in first case it's working ,but in the second case when i am using randNum variables--> newView.frame =CGRectMake(randNumX, randNumY, 80, 30);".Button appears,but still not able to click or tap

Comment: @Aiden Can you select my answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem is the Line below ,As the new child view must be according to the parent view

```
    newViewBtn.frame =CGRectMake(randNumX+5,randNumY+5,60,20);
```

writting the above as below solved the problem

```
    newViewBtn.frame =CGRectMake(5,5,60,20);
```

Answer (score 13):

When adding a custom subview to a UIButton you have to turn off the userInteractionEnabled property.

```
customView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

then add to your button.

```
[customButton addSubView:customView];
```

Otherwise your custom view intercepts touch events before the button since it's added to the top of the view stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add target like this...

```
   UIButton *newViewBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   newViewBtn.frame=CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x+5,newView.frame.origin.y+5,60,20);
   [newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // ---- add this line.....
   [newView addSubview:newViewBtn];

   -(void)btnPressed:(id)sender
   {
        NSLog(@"Btn Pressed");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot this :

```
 UIButton *newViewBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickeMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please try this.

Comment: I have added this too    
    [newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    
}

Comment: Did you logged with the method ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to add a target (the function called when the button is clicked):

```
 [newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourfunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Make sure that the function you're targeting exists, or it will crash when you click.

```
- (void) yourfunction {
    NSLog(@"Click Detected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code...

```
int randNumX = arc4random() % 150;
int randNumY = arc4random() % 200;

UIView newView=[[UIView alloc]init];

newView.frame =CGRectMake(randNumX, randNumY, 80, 30);

newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UIButton *newViewBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

newViewBtn.frame  = CGRectMake(0,0,60,20);

newViewBtn.center = newView.center;

[newViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[newView addSubview:newViewBtn];

[self.view addSubview:newView];


-(void)btnTapped:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"btnTapped");
}
```